# How can I find device model name in universal app for Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

The api I'm using requires the model name of the device being used.  In Windows 8 I would use `Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceStatus.DeviceName`.  However, I am creating a new Universal App in Windows 8.1 and the 'Microsoft.Phone' namespace seems to be missing.

How do I find the model name of the device being used with a Universal App in Windows 8.1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [EasClientDeviceInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.exchangeactivesyncprovisioning.easclientdeviceinformation) class to retrieve device information.

Sample:

```
var deviceInformation = new EasClientDeviceInformation();
var deviceName = deviceInformation.FriendlyName;
var operatingSystem = deviceInformation.OperatingSystem;
```

Answer (score 0):

For now the *easiest* (certainly not the best) answer may be to use:

`Windows.Networking.Proximity.PeerFinder.DisplayName`

*<sub>Credit for this thought goes to [this link](http://www.jarredcapellman.com/tag/windows-phone-8-personalized-name-c-get-windows-phone-name-windows-phone-name-in-code/) at [Jarred Cappellman's site](http://www.jarredcapellman.com)</sub>*